# generate sequential reference numbers

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, locking, mariadb

I am generating sequential reference numbers like complaint/1, complaint/2 when  an insertion is made. I get what the previously generated value is (complaint/2) and then increment.

**But when two users submit at the same time**, I sometimes get same reference nos for both complaints.

How do I prevent this?

```
    SELECT RIGHT(Date_format(from_financial_year_,'%Y'),2), 
       RIGHT(Date_format(to_financial_year_,'%Y'),2) 
INTO   from_financial_year_, 
       to_financial_year_;SELECT   rec.receipt_ref_no 
INTO     last_receipt_ref_num_ 
FROM     svk_apt_receipts rec 
WHERE    Replace(Substring_index(rec.receipt_ref_no, '/', 2),'REC/','') = Concat(from_financial_year_,to_financial_year_)
AND      rec.customer_id = customer_id_ 
AND      rec.association_id = association_id_ 
ORDER BY rec.receipt_id DESC limit 1;IF(last_receipt_ref_num_ IS NULL) then 
SELECT 1 
INTO   max_ref_id_; 

else 
SELECT (replace(last_receipt_ref_num_, concat('REC/',from_financial_year_,to_financial_year_,'/'),'')+1)
INTO   max_ref_id_;ENDIF;SELECT Concat('REC/',from_financial_year_,to_financial_year_,'/',max_ref_id_)
INTO   receipt_ref_no_;INSERT INTO svk_apt_receipts 
    ( 
      receipt_ref_no, paid, payable, is_paid, master_receipt_to_id, receipt_from_id, receipt_to_id, receipt_date, 
      receipt_mode, transaction_ref_no, customer_id, association_id, is_active, created_by, created_on, receipt_status_id, remarks 
    ) 
    VALUES 
      ( receipt_ref_no_, _total_amount, 0,1,3, receipt_from_id_, receipt_to_id_, Cast(Now()AS DATE), 3, _transaction_ref_no, 
      customer_id_, association_id_, 1, _created_by, Now(), 2, 'Paid through Payment Gateway' 
    );
```

Comment: set `id` as `autoincremented` in DB and manage complaint from incremented `id`

Comment: @Gulshan it works but i have problem when two users submit at the same time. when they submit at the same time, both users get same reference no

Comment: if your database column is truely set as auto_increment, (on the primary key) two users *can't* get the same id. it just violates the primary key constraint. (auto_increment is a property on a column in mysql, other database systems have similar constructs)

Comment: @Jakumi it is not auto incremented. i've edited and posted the procedure

Comment: you're doing *one* insert. just use an auto_increment key for the love of all that is holy. obviously you can wrap it all in a transaction, but your query is an abomination just because you try to avoid auto_increment, and it serves no purpose at all. it makes me angry and confused.

Comment: Just store an autoincrementing id. All the other stuff can be handled in your presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, just store an autoincrementing id. All the other stuff can be handled by trivial queries and/or your presentation layer.

By way of example...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,user INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table (user) VALUES
(1),(1),(3),(3),(5),(2),(1),(8),(4),(5),(7),(5),(5),(4),(1),(2),(3),(6),(4),(6),(1),(5),(1),(8);

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+------+
| id | user |
+----+------+
|  1 |    1 |
|  2 |    1 |
|  3 |    3 |
|  4 |    3 |
|  5 |    5 |
|  6 |    2 |
|  7 |    1 |
|  8 |    8 |
|  9 |    4 |
| 10 |    5 |
| 11 |    7 |
| 12 |    5 |
| 13 |    5 |
| 14 |    4 |
| 15 |    1 |
| 16 |    2 |
| 17 |    3 |
| 18 |    6 |
| 19 |    4 |
| 20 |    6 |
| 21 |    1 |
| 22 |    5 |
| 23 |    1 |
| 24 |    8 |
+----+------+
24 rows in set (0.01 sec)

SELECT x.*
     , COUNT(*) complaint 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.user = x.user 
   AND y.id <= x.id 
 GROUP 
    BY x.id 
 ORDER 
    BY user
     , id;
+----+------+-----------+
| id | user | complaint |
+----+------+-----------+
|  1 |    1 |         1 |
|  2 |    1 |         2 |
|  7 |    1 |         3 |
| 15 |    1 |         4 |
| 21 |    1 |         5 |
| 23 |    1 |         6 |
|  6 |    2 |         1 |
| 16 |    2 |         2 |
|  3 |    3 |         1 |
|  4 |    3 |         2 |
| 17 |    3 |         3 |
|  9 |    4 |         1 |
| 14 |    4 |         2 |
| 19 |    4 |         3 |
|  5 |    5 |         1 |
| 10 |    5 |         2 |
| 12 |    5 |         3 |
| 13 |    5 |         4 |
| 22 |    5 |         5 |
| 18 |    6 |         1 |
| 20 |    6 |         2 |
| 11 |    7 |         1 |
|  8 |    8 |         1 |
| 24 |    8 |         2 |
+----+------+-----------+
24 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Is there an explanation coming with this one?